# How to use Cross Validation in Spark's Mllib in a Java Project with logistic regression?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, cross-validation

I want want to implement the a cross validation k fold for my Java spark project which uses Mllib so that I can calculate the F score.  (here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/N19Qmziy) to a pastebin code ) Consider a set of labeled points

```
JavaRDD<LabledPoint> allData=  ...// some labled points
```

where each point is labeled "0" or "1". Therefore it might look like {[1,(2,3)],[0,(4,6)],....  }.  I managed to split my data in two parts training and verification. I created a LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS object that gives me the model

```
LogisticRegressionModel model = logisticRegression.run(trainingData.rdd())
```

I assume that before I do the model I need to do cross validation but I am not quite sure how it is implemented. Conceptually I understood the cross validation: it is a method that trains my classifier on the k parts divided data in order to find the best model.

For the F score I did the following

```
  JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> predict = valdidationData.map(new Function<LabeledPoint, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
                                public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(LabeledPoint point) {
                                    Double prediction = model.predict(point.features());
                                    return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(prediction, point.label());
                                }
                            });

BinaryClassificationMetrics metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predict.rdd());
```

`JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> f1Score =metrics.fMeasureByThreshold().toJavaRDD()`;

But the F Score is always separated I get a value for the labeled "1" and "0".

How can I use the cross validation from Mllib? In addition how can I calculate the f score correctly?

Comment: F1: I think you want to use metrics.microF1Measure, which is the weighted average of the class F-measure

Comment: Thank you, psoucy. Let me check out.

Answer (score 0):

use the CrossValidator in your Spark pipeline: [`https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaModelSelectionViaCrossValidationExample.java`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaModelSelectionViaCrossValidationExample.java)